# What is written on Kohinata's belt after Nanaka makes the changes?

Tags: karate-shoukoushi

In chapter 239 page 11 of *Karate Shoukoushi Kohinata Minoru*, Nanaka makes the changes on Kohinata's belt.

[image: Kohinata's belt with Nanaka's changes]

I can't seem to find the translation for the Japanese text on the belt after the changes.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

At first I looked at [Katakana](https://www.freejapaneselessons.com/lesson02.cfm) and [Hiragana](https://www.freejapaneselessons.com/lesson01.cfm) alphabets to see if I could find a matching symbol for the first symbol but I was unable to.

I then went to the wiki page for [Kohinata Minoru](http://kskm.wikia.com/wiki/Kohinata_Minoru) and found that the last two symbols in his name, matched the last two on his belt (those being 海流). Looking these up, I found that they mean "ocean current" (or Kairyū).

Working my way up the symbols in the belt, I saw that the second one closely resembled 向. When looking 向 up, I found that it meant toward (or Mukai).

Finally, the closest thing that I could find to the top symbol is ゆ. When looking this up, I get Yu.

Putting all of these symbols together, my best literal guess for what is written on the best is Yu kō kairyū, or Yukata ocean current. However, considering how closely a lot of the symbols on the belt match his Japanese name 小日向海流, my best guess would be that his name is what is written on the belt.

EDIT: [Kuwaly](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/93/kuwaly) showed me that the entirety of the Japanese name 小日向海流 is shown on the belt. Therefore, it is just his name that is written on the belt.

Comment: The top character is 小 if you don't totally pick up the brush between the strokes, and the 日 is visible really small between 小 and 向. (I'm agreeing with you, just clarifying why the first character looks the way it does.)

Comment: Actually, it's his name, missing the 日, thus shown 小向海流. **Actually**, there's a small 日 on the lower right of 小. I guess "just endure with this for now" indicating that the small 日 was added by them.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Thank you that was the answer I was looking for.